# How can I speed up presentation of stimuli that use multiple simultaneous windows?

Tags: psychopy

We are trying to recreate a 3x3 grid of simultaneous windows in PsychoPy, each displaying a radial optic flow pattern, as described by Cardin and Smith (2010). 
When we run the code the stimuli is too slow (taking a while to load). How can this be sped up? Would doing a single flip after drawing each of the windows help?

Cardin & Smith, 2010; Sensitivity of human visual and vestibular cortical regions to egomotion-compatible visual stimulation. Cerebral Cortex

Answer (score 2):

The details in the paper are quite sparse but just to make sure: you probably don't want to draw 9 different *Windows* but rather 9 different *stimuli* within the same (full screen) window. So I'd do something like this:

```py
import random
from psychopy import visual
win = visual.Window()

# Create 9 dotstims
stims = []
for xPos in range(-1, 2):
    for yPos in range(-1, 2):
        stims += [visual.DotStim(win, fieldPos=(xPos, yPos), fieldShape='circle', dotLife=30, speed=0.01, fieldSize = 0.2, nDots=50, dir=random.randint(0, 359))]

# Draw for 120 frames
for frame in range(120):
    for stim in stims:
        stim.draw()
    win.flip()
```

You may want to change the `dir` values to something more systematic than just random values as the above example and `fieldPos` as well. Performance-wise this is a bit borderline on my laptop as the maximum duration of the `draw`s are 11.5 ms. This is dangerously close to 16.667 ms but you can test it for yourself on your stimulus computer. Just put

```py
from psychopy import core
timerClock = core.Clock()
```

in the beginning of the script and then have use the following to loop over frames:

```py
for frame in range(120):
    timerClock.reset()
    for stim in stims:
        stim.draw()
    print timerClock.getTime()  # should be consistently below 0.016 seconds on a 60 Hz monitor.
    win.flip()
```